# Group color/ flow so that the bars create a bar chart of first

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggalluvial

I have a dataset that looks something like this:

```
results <-  as.data.frame(cbind(c("Violence", "Violence", "Violence", "Violence", "Economic", "Economic","Economic","Economic","Institutional","Institutional","Institutional","Institutional"), 
                                c("No", "No", "Yes", "Yes","No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes"),
                                c("Yes", "No", "Yes", "No","Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No"), 
                                c(3,3,1,3,4,5,8,7,6,5,4,3)))
colnames(results) <- c("Type", "Test1", "Test2", "Freq")
```

Then I create an alluvial plot with ggalluvial

```
 library(ggplot2)
  library(tidyverse)
  library(ggalluvial)

ggplot(data = results,
       aes(axis1 = Type, axis2 = Test1, axis3 = Test2,
           y = Freq)) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c("Article", "False 0s Removed", "New Flow Measure"), expand = c(.2, .05)) +
  xlab("Results") +
  geom_flow(aes(fill = Type)) +
  geom_stratum() +
  geom_text(stat = "stratum", aes(label = after_stat(stratum))) +
  theme_minimal() +
  ggtitle("Replication Summary")
```

[image]

This looks fine except for each stratum I want the vertical order to be organized by the color (Type), so that each stratum is a bar chart of sorts where I can see what percentage of each Type are No and Yes for each test. How would I change so the vertical ordering is grouped by color ($type) at each stratum (Test1 and Test2). At current the second stratum (Test 1) looks good but the the third does not (test 2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood it correctly, the only thing you have to add is `aes.bind = 'flow'` in `geom_flow()`.

```r
results <-  data.frame(Type = c("Violence", "Violence", "Violence", "Violence", "Economic", "Economic","Economic","Economic","Institutional","Institutional","Institutional","Institutional"), 
                       Test1 = c("No", "No", "Yes", "Yes","No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes"),
                       Test2 = c("Yes", "No", "Yes", "No","Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No"), 
                       Freq = c(3,3,1,3,4,5,8,7,6,5,4,3)
                       )


library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggalluvial)

ggplot(data = results,
       aes(axis1 = Type, axis2 = Test1, axis3 = Test2,
           y = Freq)) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c("Article", "False 0s Removed", "New Flow Measure"), expand = c(.2, .05)) +
  xlab("Results") +
  geom_flow(aes(fill = Type), aes.bind = 'flow') +
  geom_stratum() +
  geom_text(stat = "stratum", aes(label = after_stat(stratum))) +
  theme_minimal() +
  ggtitle("Replication Summary")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

EDIT: I am not quite sure if it is possible to get the colors in the stratas with `geom_flow()`, but you can do it with `geom_alluvial()`. For this I changed the way the example data was generated, because in your example `Freq` was not numeric and `geom_alluvial()` threw an error. Now you can add the `fill`-argument to `geom_stratum`. If one stratum cannot filled by a single Type its color will be `NA`. If you add `scale_fill_discrete(na.value = NA)` these strata will become transparent and you can see the colors.

```r
ggplot(data = results,
       aes(axis1 = Type, axis2 = Test1, axis3 = Test2,
           y = Freq)) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c("Article", "False 0s Removed", "New Flow Measure"), expand = c(.2, .05)) +
  xlab("Results") +
  geom_alluvium(aes(fill = Type), aes.bind = "alluvia") +
  geom_stratum(aes(fill = Type)) +
  scale_fill_discrete(na.value = NA) +
  geom_text(stat = "stratum", aes(label = after_stat(stratum))) +
  theme_minimal() +
  ggtitle("Replication Summary")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Perfect. Is there a way to make the stratum transparent so the stratum form a bar graph of sorts?

Comment: @BenjaminKrick Glad to help. Have a look at my edit on how to make the strata transparent.